# Mojito install error

Tags: node.js, mojito

On Ubuntu 12.10 with Node 0.6.19 and NPM v 1.1.4 I get the following message when trying to install from NPM source and the cloned GitHub as root (sudo):

```
npm ERR! error installing js-yaml@1.0.2
npm ERR! error installing mojito@0.4.9-2
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mojito/node_modules/___yuidocjs.npm/package/tests/out/files/input_charts_StackedAreaSeries.js.html'
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/me/devpath/mojito/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-17-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mojito"
npm ERR! cwd /home/me/devpath/mojito
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mojito/node_modules/___yuidocjs.npm/package   /tests/out/files/input_charts_StackedAreaSeries.js.html
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mojito/node_modules/___yuidocjs.npm   /package/tests/out/files/input_charts_StackedAreaSeries.js.html
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mojito/node_modules/___yuidocjs.npm/package/tests/out/files/input_charts_StackedAreaSeries.js.html'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:285:17)

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mojito/node_modules/js-yaml/bin/js-yaml.js'
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/me/devpath/mojito/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-17-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mojito"
npm ERR! cwd /home/me/devpath/mojito
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mojito/node_modules/js-yaml/bin/js-yaml.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mojito/node_modules/js-yaml/bin/js-yaml.js'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/devpath/mojito/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

I'm at a loss. Why would I get a chmod error as sudo? Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with the same problem for the last hour. I still don't know what the exact problem is, though I've found a number of people reporting the same bug. The issue seems to be related to the version of npm you have. I did these steps to resolve the issue:

1) Updated Node.

2) Updated npm. (sudo npm install -g npm)

3) Cleared the cache. (sudo npm clear cache)

Comment: this got it working? I eventually abandoned Mojito and went back to my own Express implementation. Sad b/c I had a lot of hope for Mojito